# mathjax-node: different output when formatted on webpage than in node project

Tags: mathjax

I am getting different behavior between mathjax on a webpage and mathjax-node. When I load it on the webpage I get the correct output that I am looking for. For example I have a `line = $_{a} ^{x} A $` where I want the superscript and subscript above and below each other. It works fine if I convert it on the webpage however when I try to run it through mathjax-node I get what would look like this `_{ax}A`. Here is everything related to mathjax in my code:

```
var mathjax = require('mathjax-node');

mathjax.config({   MathJax: {   } });

mathjax.start();

async function formatMath(line) {
try{
  var line;
  if(line.indexOf('$')==-1)
    return line;

  while(line.indexOf('$') > -1){
    var re = /\$(.*?)\$/;
    var match = re.exec(line)[0];
    var math = match.slice(1, -1);


    let result = await mathjax.typeset({
      math: math,
      format: "inline-TeX",
      html: true
    });

    line = line.replace(match, result.html);
    if(line=="$_{a} ^{x} A $"){
      console.log(line);
      console.log(match);
      console.log(math);
    }


  }
  return line;
} catch(err) {
    if(err) {
      return Error(`Error at formMath(): ${err}`);
    }
  }
}
```

[Example of what I am getting using the above function with '$_{a} ^{x} A $'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlaRi.png)

[Example of what I want when I just add `html = "\\(_{a} ^{x} A \\)";` directly into the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ7jX.png)

This is my exact output from above:

```
<span class="mjx-chtml"><span class="mjx-math" aria-label="_{a} ^{x} A "><span c
lass="mjx-mrow" aria-hidden="true"><span class="mjx-msubsup"><span class="mjx-ba
se"><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char"></span></span></span><span class
="mjx-stack" style="vertical-align: -0.156em;"><span class="mjx-sup" style="font
-size: 70.7%; padding-bottom: 0.255em; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0.071em
;"><span class="mjx-texatom" style=""><span class="mjx-mrow"><span class="mjx-mi
"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.225em; padding-bo
ttom: 0.298em;">x</span></span></span></span></span><span class="mjx-sub" style=
"font-size: 70.7%; padding-right: 0.071em;"><span class="mjx-texatom" style=""><
span class="mjx-mrow"><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I
" style="padding-top: 0.225em; padding-bottom: 0.298em;">a</span></span></span><
/span></span></span></span><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-m
ath-I" style="padding-top: 0.519em; padding-bottom: 0.298em;">A</span></span></s
pan></span></span>
$_{a} ^{x} A $
_{a} ^{x} A
```

Note that I have already tried converting my regex to `\\((.*)\\)`.

I tried to play around with `useGlobalCache` and other options with no luck. I do not understand why this is happening or if it has to do with how my formulas are being formatted. I am using **"mathjax-node": "2.1.1"**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you share a minimal example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a full example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML sample is actually ok.

I'm guessing you're not generating and applying the CSS. This is a separate step for server-side processing since it's a one-time job.

You need to run `typeset` with the `css` option to have mathjax-node add the CSS declarations to the result object, cf. https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node#typesetoptions-callback.

Here's the HTML from your OP with the CSS applied.

```css
.mjx-chtml {display: inline-block; line-height: 0; text-indent: 0; text-align: left; text-transform: none; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 100%; font-size-adjust: none; letter-spacing: normal; word-wrap: normal; word-spacing: normal; white-space: nowrap; float: none; direction: ltr; max-width: none; max-height: none; min-width: 0; min-height: 0; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 1px 0}
.MJXc-display {display: block; text-align: center; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0}
.mjx-chtml[tabindex]:focus, body :focus .mjx-chtml[tabindex] {display: inline-table}
.mjx-full-width {text-align: center; display: table-cell!important; width: 10000em}
.mjx-math {display: inline-block; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0}
.mjx-math * {display: inline-block; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box!important; -moz-box-sizing: content-box!important; box-sizing: content-box!important; text-align: left}
.mjx-numerator {display: block; text-align: center}
.mjx-denominator {display: block; text-align: center}
.MJXc-stacked {height: 0; position: relative}
.MJXc-stacked > * {position: absolute}
.MJXc-bevelled > * {display: inline-block}
.mjx-stack {display: inline-block}
.mjx-op {display: block}
.mjx-under {display: table-cell}
.mjx-over {display: block}
.mjx-over > * {padding-left: 0px!important; padding-right: 0px!important}
.mjx-under > * {padding-left: 0px!important; padding-right: 0px!important}
.mjx-stack > .mjx-sup {display: block}
.mjx-stack > .mjx-sub {display: block}
.mjx-prestack > .mjx-presup {display: block}
.mjx-prestack > .mjx-presub {display: block}
.mjx-delim-h > .mjx-char {display: inline-block}
.mjx-surd {vertical-align: top}
.mjx-mphantom * {visibility: hidden}
.mjx-merror {background-color: #FFFF88; color: #CC0000; border: 1px solid #CC0000; padding: 2px 3px; font-style: normal; font-size: 90%}
.mjx-annotation-xml {line-height: normal}
.mjx-menclose > svg {fill: none; stroke: currentColor}
.mjx-mtr {display: table-row}
.mjx-mlabeledtr {display: table-row}
.mjx-mtd {display: table-cell; text-align: center}
.mjx-label {display: table-row}
.mjx-box {display: inline-block}
.mjx-block {display: block}
.mjx-span {display: inline}
.mjx-char {display: block; white-space: pre}
.mjx-itable {display: inline-table; width: auto}
.mjx-row {display: table-row}
.mjx-cell {display: table-cell}
.mjx-table {display: table; width: 100%}
.mjx-line {display: block; height: 0}
.mjx-strut {width: 0; padding-top: 1em}
.mjx-vsize {width: 0}
.MJXc-space1 {margin-left: .167em}
.MJXc-space2 {margin-left: .222em}
.MJXc-space3 {margin-left: .278em}
.mjx-ex-box-test {position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 1px; height: 60ex}
.mjx-line-box-test {display: table!important}
.mjx-line-box-test span {display: table-cell!important; width: 10000em!important; min-width: 0; max-width: none; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0}
.MJXc-TeX-unknown-R {font-family: monospace; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal}
.MJXc-TeX-unknown-I {font-family: monospace; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal}
.MJXc-TeX-unknown-B {font-family: monospace; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold}
.MJXc-TeX-unknown-BI {font-family: monospace; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold}
.MJXc-TeX-ams-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-ams-R,MJXc-TeX-ams-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-cal-B {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-B,MJXc-TeX-cal-Bx,MJXc-TeX-cal-Bw}
.MJXc-TeX-frak-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-R,MJXc-TeX-frak-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-frak-B {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-B,MJXc-TeX-frak-Bx,MJXc-TeX-frak-Bw}
.MJXc-TeX-math-BI {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-BI,MJXc-TeX-math-BIx,MJXc-TeX-math-BIw}
.MJXc-TeX-sans-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-R,MJXc-TeX-sans-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-sans-B {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-B,MJXc-TeX-sans-Bx,MJXc-TeX-sans-Bw}
.MJXc-TeX-sans-I {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-I,MJXc-TeX-sans-Ix,MJXc-TeX-sans-Iw}
.MJXc-TeX-script-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-script-R,MJXc-TeX-script-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-type-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-type-R,MJXc-TeX-type-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-cal-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-R,MJXc-TeX-cal-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-main-B {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-B,MJXc-TeX-main-Bx,MJXc-TeX-main-Bw}
.MJXc-TeX-main-I {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-I,MJXc-TeX-main-Ix,MJXc-TeX-main-Iw}
.MJXc-TeX-main-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-R,MJXc-TeX-main-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-math-I {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-I,MJXc-TeX-math-Ix,MJXc-TeX-math-Iw}
.MJXc-TeX-size1-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size1-R,MJXc-TeX-size1-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-size2-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size2-R,MJXc-TeX-size2-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-size3-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size3-R,MJXc-TeX-size3-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-size4-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size4-R,MJXc-TeX-size4-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-vec-R {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-R,MJXc-TeX-vec-Rw}
.MJXc-TeX-vec-B {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-B,MJXc-TeX-vec-Bx,MJXc-TeX-vec-Bw}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-ams-R; src: local('MathJax_AMS'), local('MathJax_AMS-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-ams-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_AMS-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_AMS-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_AMS-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-B; src: local('MathJax_Caligraphic Bold'), local('MathJax_Caligraphic-Bold')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-Bx; src: local('MathJax_Caligraphic'); font-weight: bold}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-Bw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Caligraphic-Bold.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Caligraphic-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Caligraphic-Bold.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-R; src: local('MathJax_Fraktur'), local('MathJax_Fraktur-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Fraktur-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Fraktur-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Fraktur-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-B; src: local('MathJax_Fraktur Bold'), local('MathJax_Fraktur-Bold')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-Bx; src: local('MathJax_Fraktur'); font-weight: bold}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-frak-Bw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Fraktur-Bold.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Fraktur-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Fraktur-Bold.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-BI; src: local('MathJax_Math BoldItalic'), local('MathJax_Math-BoldItalic')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-BIx; src: local('MathJax_Math'); font-weight: bold; font-style: italic}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-BIw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Math-BoldItalic.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Math-BoldItalic.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Math-BoldItalic.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-R; src: local('MathJax_SansSerif'), local('MathJax_SansSerif-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_SansSerif-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_SansSerif-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_SansSerif-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-B; src: local('MathJax_SansSerif Bold'), local('MathJax_SansSerif-Bold')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-Bx; src: local('MathJax_SansSerif'); font-weight: bold}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-Bw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_SansSerif-Bold.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_SansSerif-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_SansSerif-Bold.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-I; src: local('MathJax_SansSerif Italic'), local('MathJax_SansSerif-Italic')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-Ix; src: local('MathJax_SansSerif'); font-style: italic}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-sans-Iw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_SansSerif-Italic.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_SansSerif-Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_SansSerif-Italic.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-script-R; src: local('MathJax_Script'), local('MathJax_Script-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-script-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Script-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Script-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Script-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-type-R; src: local('MathJax_Typewriter'), local('MathJax_Typewriter-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-type-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Typewriter-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Typewriter-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Typewriter-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-R; src: local('MathJax_Caligraphic'), local('MathJax_Caligraphic-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-cal-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Caligraphic-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Caligraphic-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Caligraphic-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-B; src: local('MathJax_Main Bold'), local('MathJax_Main-Bold')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-Bx; src: local('MathJax_Main'); font-weight: bold}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-Bw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Main-Bold.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Bold.woff')format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Bold.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-I; src: local('MathJax_Main Italic'), local('MathJax_Main-Italic')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-Ix; src: local('MathJax_Main'); font-style: italic}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-Iw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Main-Italic.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Italic.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-R; src: local('MathJax_Main'), local('MathJax_Main-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-main-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Main-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-I; src: local('MathJax_Math Italic'), local('MathJax_Math-Italic')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-Ix; src: local('MathJax_Math'); font-style: italic}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-math-Iw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Math-Italic.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Math-Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Math-Italic.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size1-R; src: local('MathJax_Size1'), local('MathJax_Size1-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size1-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Size1-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size1-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size1-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size2-R; src: local('MathJax_Size2'), local('MathJax_Size2-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size2-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Size2-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size2-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size2-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size3-R; src: local('MathJax_Size3'), local('MathJax_Size3-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size3-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Size3-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size3-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size3-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size4-R; src: local('MathJax_Size4'), local('MathJax_Size4-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-size4-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Size4-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size4-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size4-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-R; src: local('MathJax_Vector'), local('MathJax_Vector-Regular')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-Rw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Vector-Regular.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Vector-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Vector-Regular.otf') format('opentype')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-B; src: local('MathJax_Vector Bold'), local('MathJax_Vector-Bold')}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-Bx; src: local('MathJax_Vector'); font-weight: bold}
@font-face {font-family: MJXc-TeX-vec-Bw; src /*1*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/eot/MathJax_Vector-Bold.eot'); src /*2*/: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Vector-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Vector-Bold.otf') format('opentype')}
```

```html
<span class="mjx-chtml"><span class="mjx-math" aria-label="_{a} ^{x} A "><span class="mjx-mrow" aria-hidden="true"><span class="mjx-msubsup"><span class="mjx-ba
se"><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char"></span></span></span><span class="mjx-stack" style="vertical-align: -0.156em;"><span class="mjx-sup" style="font-size: 70.7%; padding-bottom: 0.255em; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0.071em;"><span class="mjx-texatom" style=""><span class="mjx-mrow"><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.225em; padding-bottom: 0.298em;">x</span></span></span></span></span><span class="mjx-sub" style="font-size: 70.7%; padding-right: 0.071em;"><span class="mjx-texatom" style=""><span class="mjx-mrow"><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I
" style="padding-top: 0.225em; padding-bottom: 0.298em;">a</span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.519em; padding-bottom: 0.298em;">A</span></span></span></span></span>
```

Comment: Nice. I was looking for a CSS file somewhere but didn't realize it was being generated in the result! Before I approve the answer one last question - I am applying math to multiple lines within a single webpage so is there 1 universal css document that can be applied? When I make the above css into a file it works but what happens when the CSS is changed a little bit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what change in the CSS you are expecting. The CSS output will generate the full stylesheet so that won't change as such. However, if you update MathJax to a different version (e.g., by up/downgrading mathjax-node), then there might of course be changes. But that won't affect content you've already generated unless you update that content and its stylesheet. Depending on the actual change in MathJax, you might be able to update just the stylesheet but often changes occur in both markup and styles. I usually regenerate everything and run visual regression tests.

Comment: Is there a single CSS file somewhere of all the relevant MathJax CSS, that can be simply included on the page with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="…">` or something like that? (This is [how KaTeX does it](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html) for example.) For server-side processing of a typical page with dozens or hundreds of math blocks, is the expectation that one will take the css string from the result of each call to `.typeset` and add each of them individually onto the page?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR for mathjax-node the css "output" generates such a stylesheet - it's not optimized per equation but all there is. For mathjax v3 (which can run in nodejs directly) there are APIs such as MathJax.chtmlStylesheet but IIRC chtmlStylesheet no longer generates the whole stylesheet (since it's huge). You might want to ask a new question for v3.